# Generate number in range: Am I accessing my array improperly?

Tags: javascript, arrays

When a user enters a comment on my site, I would like to generate a random avatar for that comment from an array of preselected gifs.

I am using Math.random() to select an object in my array and return an index that corresponds to an item in my array. However, I am having a difficult time accessing my `avatars` array. I keep receiving `undefined` when I run this code.

I based the code off of these [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random#Getting_a_random_integer_between_two_values_inclusive).

```
const randomAvatar = () => {
  const avatars = [
    {
      name: 'cool doge',
      image: 'https://emojis.slackmojis.com/emojis/images/1520808873/3643/cool-doge.gif?1520808873' 
    },
    {
      name: 'catty ping',
      image: 'https://emojis.slackmojis.com/emojis/images/1498862355/2559/cattyping.gif?1498862355' 
    },
    {
      name: 'cowbell',
      image: 'https://emojis.slackmojis.com/emojis/images/1495219406/2284/more_cowbell.gif?1495219406'
    },
    {
      name: 'hypnotoad',
      image: 'https://emojis.slackmojis.com/emojis/images/1450319455/129/hypnotoad.gif?1450319455'
    },
  ]

    let min = Math.ceil(avatars[3].image);
    let max = Math.floor(avatars[0].image);

     return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min)
}
```

I have tried several debugging steps but have not been successful. I would like to be able to call `randomAvatar()` and receive the gif url in return.

#### Thank you for your time and advice!

Comment: `Math.ceil(avatars[3].iamge)` what you're trying to achieve here ?

Comment: `min` and `max` should just be `0` and `avatars.length` respectively.

Comment: And then you should probably do `index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min]; return avatars[index];`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
const randomAvatar = () => {

    const avatars = [
    {
      name: 'cool doge',
      image: 'https://emojis.slackmojis.com/emojis/images/1520808873/3643/cool-doge.gif?1520808873' 
    },
    {
      name: 'catty ping',
      image: 'https://emojis.slackmojis.com/emojis/images/1498862355/2559/cattyping.gif?1498862355' 
    },
    {
      name: 'cowbell',
      image: 'https://emojis.slackmojis.com/emojis/images/1495219406/2284/more_cowbell.gif?1495219406'
    },
    {
      name: 'hypnotoad',
      image: 'https://emojis.slackmojis.com/emojis/images/1450319455/129/hypnotoad.gif?1450319455'
    },
  ]



   let min = 0;
   let max = avatars.length-1;

    let url_num = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min);

    return avatars[url_num].image;

}
```

Returns a random URL

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to return a random avatar just use [`Array.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length). As your minimum value is 0, you don't have to do anything else:

```
const randomAvatar = () => {
  const avatars = [
    {
      name: 'cool doge',
      image: 'https://emojis.slackmojis.com/emojis/images/1520808873/3643/cool-doge.gif?1520808873' 
    },
    {
      name: 'catty ping',
      image: 'https://emojis.slackmojis.com/emojis/images/1498862355/2559/cattyping.gif?1498862355' 
    },
    {
      name: 'cowbell',
      image: 'https://emojis.slackmojis.com/emojis/images/1495219406/2284/more_cowbell.gif?1495219406'
    },
    {
      name: 'hypnotoad',
      image: 'https://emojis.slackmojis.com/emojis/images/1450319455/129/hypnotoad.gif?1450319455'
    },
  ]

    const max = avatars.length;
    return avatars[Math.floor(Math.random() * avatars.length)]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as `avatars[0].image` and `avatars[3].image` are strings (the gif URL), you are doing `math.ceil` and `math.floor` of a string, that will always return NaN, and then you are returning a random number between NaN and NaN.

The right range should be [0, avatars.length-1]

Then, the right code should be:

```
const randomAvatar = () => {
  const avatars = [
    {
      name: 'cool doge',
      image: 'https://emojis.slackmojis.com/emojis/images/1520808873/3643/cool-doge.gif?1520808873' 
    },
    {
      name: 'catty ping',
      image: 'https://emojis.slackmojis.com/emojis/images/1498862355/2559/cattyping.gif?1498862355' 
    },
    {
      name: 'cowbell',
      image: 'https://emojis.slackmojis.com/emojis/images/1495219406/2284/more_cowbell.gif?1495219406'
    },
    {
      name: 'hypnotoad',
      image: 'https://emojis.slackmojis.com/emojis/images/1450319455/129/hypnotoad.gif?1450319455'
    },
  ]

    const max = avatars.length;
    return avatars[Math.floor(Math.random() * avatars.length)]
}
```

The function for the random number is simplified because min is 0.

Also, with this code you are not returning the random number, but the image of the avatar in the random position.